# Xcode for mac OS X 10.6.3?

Tags: macos

Is there a version of xcode available for mac OS X 10.6.3? I did several searches on google but the only versions that i find is for 10.6.6 and up.

And xcode 3.2.5 is for leopard and not snow leopard.

I want to use it for developing for Iphone and Ipad.

Thanks.

Comment: Some old versions of xcode will probably work. But if you want to use it to develop for iphone/ipad you may need to use a newer version of xcode and a newer version of OsX or Apple will likely not accept your submission (because the old xcode would not be able to compile for the newer versions of iOS).

Comment: 10.6.3?  Does Apple not provide updates to snow leopard anymore?

Comment: have you found the xcode? @user1675567 ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked here: http://connect.apple.com/ 
You need to login using your Apple ID. Also, as Analog File mentioned, that version is probably deprecated and you won't be able to submit your app to the App Store if you build one with it.

Comment: I don't have to submit an app on the app store. I just want to use it for learning purposes.

Comment: Good, then you should be able to install an older version and use it on your system.